# StackOverflow migration option

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, flagging, off-topic

On StackOverflow, there are multiple migration options when you want to flag a post as off topic:

[image]

On WP.SE, we only have the option for our meta.

We get a lot questions that are not specific to WordPress and belong on StackOverflow. Wouldn't it be useful to have a **belongs on stackoverflow.com** option in our list?

Comment: +1 Well, what a coincidence. I _came to meta_ right now to post exactly this question, as I've asked myself that for some time now, and just voted another question as off-topic (while it'd fit for Stack Overflow). :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We added Stack Overflow and Webmasters as migration paths for you all. Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Stats wise in last 90 days we had:

- 24 migrations to SO (8% rejected)
- 9 migrations to webmasters (none rejected)

These would make sense to add as migration routes, if higher powers agree and make it so.