# Disable migration targets for blocked users

Tags: feature-request, migration

We got the [list of common migration targets](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2433/stackoverflow-migration-option) recently. Nice. Thank you.

But some users are [question banned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers) on at least one of these sites, and we cannot see that early enough. Not so nice.

Please **disable** options that are not available. Maybe make this information visible to moderators only. But stop giving us a red error message when we try to migrate a question when we didn’t do anything wrong. It’s the system’s error, not ours. :)